# Eclipse Android Project Created and Always Missing R Element

Tags: android, eclipse

I am Working In Eclipse For Android development.Problem is that When Ever I Create new Android Project in Eclipse It Creates the Project and in Source file always `R`  is Red Underlined.I Don't Understand Why This happening Even I created New Work Space and also Created Project With New Location.Please any one Help me what may the issue and How Can I Resolve it.Thanks

Comment: check if you have android sdk build tools installed from the sdk manager

Comment: Select following from eclipse : Windows > show view > problems and see what is the problem. It might be some problem in your resource folder.

Comment: Have you tried clean on the project. Also is R imported in your activity?

Comment: I Don't Undersstand What r u suggesting

Comment: @Lohit I have Tried To Clean Several Times and Also Imported R In Project But When I Import R It Show Error on `Main Activity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some "errors" when creating an Android project in Eclipse as well. For me it's sufficient clicking the project and pressing F5 to refresh.
If R.java is corrupted try Project > Clean...

Comment: No Sir Its Enough for My Problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834319/eclipse-project-clean-removes-my-additional-android-src-folder-how-to-fi/14835162#14835162) and the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026167/android-project-suddenly-ruined-cant-find-r-object/15026333#15026333). Check if your layouts contain any errors (this has to be done manually or automatically only with Android Studio). Search for incorrectly closed tags like `<string>` - `</string>`.