# Creating R files fails in ADT 22 when bulding from ant and modifing the manifest file

Tags: android, ant, build, adt

I have a a project with a lib inside it. The project has no resource of its own and all the reoources are in the lib 
On my build machine I'm using ant to build the project.
Until upgrading to ADT22 build was ok when building both from eclipse and ant.
After the upgrade the build fails for the cases when I modify the main project manifest in the ant build.xml. If I don't modify the manifest in the ant build.xml then the build is passed well. The problem that I see is that in that case R$ files are not generated in my main project but only in my lib project.

**Edit:**
The problem was because I changed the package name in the manifest during the ant build. 
I Have two build.xml files. One for my main project and one for my lib project.
I moved the ant task that modify the package name to the main application build.xml to be the first -compile target depends.

```
<target name="-compile" depends="-backupFiles,-replaceManifestgName,-build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile>
```

And this fixed my problem.
I guess something in the way ADT22 handle the ant build was change and this is what cause the problem since with previes ADTI didnt Have problems

Comment: try this one just asked some one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440595/r-cannot-be-resolved-may-have-wrong-build-path-or-libraries-import/17440632?noredirect=1#comment25338733_17440632

Comment: this is related to building from eclipse but I don't have problem building from eclipse. Only when building from ant and modifying the manifest during the build.xml

Answer (score 0):

try to close ecplise and run it again

Comment: try joel answer clean and refresh project

Comment: I tried and didn't work. note that the strange thing is that the problem happens only when my ant modify the manifest. If I modify the manifest manually before I run the ant all works well

Comment: then you should track what ant writes to your manifest maybe its something related to android minimum sdk version or some little modification

Comment: it writes what I ask it to modify. After the ant fails If without changing anything I try to build from eclipse the build is ok

Answer (score 0):

When switching between ant and Eclipse you need to clean the project first. So either `ant clean` or `Eclipse>Project>Clean...`.

Running `android update project -p ./` may help, too. It seems the behaviour started appearing since ADT 22.

Comment: I do clean all dirs before doing the build so its not the issue.<BR> running android update also didn't change anything in my build.xml

Comment: Is your project a library? It all seems as if ADT is not so compatible with an older ant, anymore. Ant in the repos, unless in rolling releases, appears to be sitting at 1.8.x. Cleaning the project usually fixes the ant/ADT shenanigans

Comment: yes. most of my code is in a library. and Im using ant 1.8.3 . and I do clean inside the ant all directories before starting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I changed the package name in the manifest during the ant build. 
I Have two build.xml files. One for my main project and one for my lib project.
I moved the ant task that modify the package name to the main application build.xml to be the first -compile target depends.

```
<target name="-compile" depends="-backupFiles,-replaceManifestgName,-build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile>
```

And this fixed my problem.
I guess something in the way ADT22 handle the ant build was change and this is what cause the problem since with previes ADTI didnt Have problems