# error when importing android projects into eclipse of lynda.com exercise file

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having difficulties importing '*The lynda.com android app development with java essential training*' exercise files into eclipse.

I keep getting some java errors like this.

```
Paste error here please.
```

Can someone help me out with this problem? Currently I am using

1. "Android SDK r22.0.1"
2. "ADT 22 plugin for eclipse"
3. "JDK 6x64"
4. "JRE 6x64"
5. "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.2 juno"

Comment: Kindly post the error

Comment: what error post something related error?

Comment: i have no reputation so i cant even post the snapshot of error

Comment: You can just add a link of a screenshot, upload it to imgur or something. Or just type it.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The declared package "com.leebrimelow.intents" does not match the expected package "gen.com.leebrimelow.intents" R.java /Explicit_Intents/gen/com/leebrimelow/intents line 8 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable Main.java /Explicit_Intents/src/com/leebrimelow/explicit_intents line 22 Java Problem
The import com.leebrimelow cannot be resolved Main.java /Explicit_Intents/src/com/leebrimelow/explicit_intents line 3 Java Problem
The declared package "com.leebrimelow.explicit_intents" does not match the expected package "src.com.l

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440595/r-cannot-be-resolved-may-have-wrong-build-path-or-libraries-import/17440632#17440632

Comment: your given link i have tried but it doesnt solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Then It might be because, there may be some problem in your `res` folder,

```
 1.The Main reason might be there could be wrong import file of R.java. 
     So Remove, if any import android.R;
    2. There be some errors in your xml files
    3.Try rebuilding and cleaning your project or
    4. Close all files, clean project, restart Eclipse.
```

Comment: there named a file R.java but the problem is with package containing other java programs

Answer (score 1):

In the project right click Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties