# My MainActivity class throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when extends ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, android-actionbaractivity

I followed the instructions indicated in other threads on how to import external libraries, but after importing android-support-v7-appcompat.jar into the Referenced Libraries of my Android project (in ADT v.22.0.5) I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
}
```

Can someone please shed some light?

[image]

Comment: Did you added v4 jar also? if not that should be add to project.

Comment: see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440595/r-cannot-be-resolved-may-have-wrong-build-path-or-libraries-import/17440632#17440632

Comment: Why not adding the whole project as library...

Comment: The only other jars are: android.jar and android-support-v4.jar

Comment: Then import action bar of v4 not of v7.

Comment: remove the v7 jar and checked the v4 jar in order and export and make clean and build project

Comment: ensure that android private libraries and other 3rd party libraries are checked in "Order and Export" tab.

Comment: They are checked, but I get the same error.

Comment: I fixed it following the instructions indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it following these instructions:

1. [How to set up ActionBarCompat in Eclipse](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-setting-up-actionbarcompat-support-library-in-eclipse/)
2. [How to implement Action Bar using ActionBarCompat](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-action-bar-using-actionbarcompat-support-library-in-android)

Answer (score 10):

Go the "Java Build Path" -> Order and export -> check all checkboxes -> clean -> build -> run

Comment: I fixed it following the instructions indicated in my answer.

Comment: This was an easy fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

**You must add the class path to your new library.**

> **You can see a file named *.classpath*, specify the path to your new
>   library.**

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="<path to your .jar file>"/>
```

Comment: I fixed it following the instructions indicated in my answer.