# while extending Acitvity it runs normally but whenever extending ActionBarActivity app goes crash

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

this is the error that i got

```
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390): Process: com.example.nevigation, PID: 1390
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nevigation/com.example.nevigation.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.nevigation.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nevigation-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.nevigation-1, /system/lib]]
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.nevigation.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nevigation-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.nevigation-1, /system/lib]]
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-24 01:49:30.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
```

Comment: which one you use Androidstudio or Eclipse?

Comment: have you added your activity in Manifest file?

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated, but the question seems duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565956/my-mainactivity-class-throws-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-when-extends-actio

Comment: i have tried everythng that was posted by others but still its not working i can not find solution of it

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the SupportActionBarActivity instead of ActionBar Activity

Comment: there is no such class (SupportActionBarActivity) in library , i cant get it how to get it ?

Comment: The one to be used now is `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: You will be able to use that class if you add `appcompat-v7` library into your project.

Comment: i added but still not

Answer (score 0):

below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` then clead and build the project again.
Hope this will help you, or paste the complete logcat error.

Comment: you have `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.nevigation.MainActivity"` means it is not getting the .class file. i think you should delete the apk file created then clean the project and rebuild the apk or try [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-action-bar-using-actionbarcompat-support-library-in-android/) if you are following the link then add `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"` to build.gradle of Module: App

Answer (score 0):

Check for the package mentioned in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

It should be `<activity name="com.example.nevtest.MainActivity"`. The package specified here should be the same as the first line of your `MainActivity.java` file.

This is usually an effect of moving around your `Activity` class through different packages. Any change in the package of your `Activity` should reflect in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.nevigation.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Can you paste here the very first line of your MainActivity.java?

Comment: Just the first line that starts with `package` is required for me to see if there is a problem in your manifest...

Comment: private DrawerLayout drawerlayout;private ListView listview;String planet[];
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawerlayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
        planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,planet));
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);  
    }

Comment: many times i delete the project and and remake the project by other name but stil give that error

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

Comment: see alose package

Comment: package com.example.nevtest;

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.nevtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

Comment: Thats strange... can you copy the whole of your `<activity>` part of your manifest?

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.nevtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: The error log you posted seems to be trying to start `com.example.nevigation.MainActivity` and you say it is defined as `com.example.nevtest.MainActivity` in your manifest... Is there a duplicate entry for that activity in your manifest file?

Comment: i told you i delete that previous project that log was i sent i made new project bt same thing app crash again

Comment: EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(818): Process: com.example.nevtest,
 E/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
 E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
 E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
t android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.jav
 com.example.nevtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)

Comment: This is a completely different crash. I think you are using very old SDK. You can probably try changing `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` and change your app theme in styles.xml to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, this should get your app started. The other proper alternative would be to update your SDK and the version of libraries that you are using.

Comment: its kitkat version , API 19

Comment: How about the version of appcompat that you are using?

Comment: i dont know that , how to find out the version of appcompat?

Comment: What are you using? Eclipse?